# Is it possible to make two backgrounds in manifest.json(pwa)?

Tags: javascript

Can I write some script in manifest.json that will take a key from local storage, namely the theme color, and depending on this key (light, dark) determine the background color of the pwa application?

I read something similar about manifest V3, but I didn’t fully understand it.  Perhaps you can still write something in sw.js, but there is no idea how to do it.